# Beth sequence fixed points

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Apparently, for all ordinals $\alpha > \omega$, the following two are equivalent:

- $|L_{\alpha}| = |V_{\alpha}|$
- $\alpha = \beth_{\alpha}$

Where $L$ is the constructible universe and $V$ the von Neumann universe and $\beth_{\alpha}$ is the Beth sequence indexed on $\alpha$ (the Beth sequence is defined by $\beth_0 = \aleph_0$; $\beth_{\alpha + 1} = 2^{\beth_\alpha}$ and $\beth_\lambda = \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} \beth_{\alpha}$).

We know that if $\alpha \geq \omega$, then $|L_{\alpha}| = |\alpha|$. I thought about showing that $|V_{\alpha}| = \beth_{\alpha}$ and we know that $\beth_{\alpha}$ is a cardinal, so then $|L_{\alpha}| = \alpha$ and we have the equivalence.

But how can I show that $|V_{\alpha}| = \beth_{\alpha}$? I thought about induction, but it is very hard to find a base case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof that $|V_\alpha|=\beth_\alpha$ is in fact not true. $|V_{\omega+\alpha}|=\beth_\alpha$. However, after $\alpha=\omega^2$, you get that $\omega+\alpha=\alpha$. So this must certainly be the case for a $\beth$-fixed point cardinal.

Now you can use induction to finish your proof quite easily.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The following induction steps are indeed easy. I guess that the only thing then left to show is that if $|L_{\alpha}| = |V_{\alpha}|$, then $\alpha \geq \omega^2$

Comment: Well, one caveat is that the equality holds for $0$. But also if you know that $L_\alpha$ and $\alpha$ have the same cardinality then it means $V_\alpha$ also have the same cardinality, which is also $\beth_{\operatorname{otp}(\alpha\setminus\omega) }$. So in particular $\alpha$ is a cardinal, so it is not a countable ordinal. Or, you know, just by induction.

Comment: I don't get why $\alpha$ has to be a cardinal. If we assume that $|L_{\alpha}| = |V_{\alpha}|$ and we know that $|V_{\omega + \alpha}| = \beth_{\alpha}$. Since $\alpha > \omega$, we can write $\alpha$ as $\omega + \beta$ for some $\beta$. And thus $|\alpha| = |V_{\omega + \beta}| = \beth_{\beta}$. But this still doesn't mean that $\alpha$ is a cardinal.

Comment: Beth(a) is always a cardinal. So if a=Beth(a), then...